# JS Script error in WebBrowser control Window.Error

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm working with Visual Basic in VS 2012. Here's a pastebin of my class I'm trying to set up. [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/dKfvVL5C)
I was following along with MSDN here. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.scripterrorssuppressed(v=vs.110).aspx)

The main portion of the code in question is this:

```
    Dim SenderBrowser As WebCommander = CType(sender, WebCommander)

    If SenderBrowser.Document IsNot Nothing AndAlso SenderBrowser.Document.Window IsNot Nothing Then
        AddHandler SenderBrowser.Document.Window.Error, AddressOf WebCommander_SuppressErrorDialogs

        If SenderBrowser.Document.Window.Frames.Count > 0 Then

            For Each FrameSource As HtmlWindow In SenderBrowser.Document.Window.Frames
                AddHandler FrameSource.Document.Window.Error, AddressOf WebCommander_SuppressErrorDialogs
            Next

        End If
    End If
```

and this

```
Private Sub WebCommander_SuppressErrorDialogs(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As HtmlElementErrorEventArgs)
    e.Handled = True
End Sub
```

In the SuppressErrorDialogs Sub if I put this

```
    MsgBox(e.Url.ToString & " " & e.Handled.ToString)
```

Then I get a message box with the URL and True but I still get the script error saying Yes or No to allow scripts to continue to run. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

I've tried several combinations with no success. And just to be aware, I can't simply set SenderBrowser.SuppressScriptErrors to True as I need SSL and Login windows to still appear. The way I'm testing if the alert comes up or not is with `onclick="brokefun();"` a JS function that doesn't exist, however the alert comes up other ways as well. I don't have control over the server code.